# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, django

Меня уже просто выбесила эта ошибка...Я не понимаю как от нее избавится. В общем у меня есть страница с отображением категории, ну то есть не список категории ,а посты в определенной категории(это выглядит так: категории/категория(и в "категории" выводятся посты связанные с ней).Ошибка связана с тем что queryset не может быть None и из-за этого, как я понимаю выходит ошибка:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'.Я даже пытался сделать  проверку если есть посты и использовал exists(),но мне не помогало. Как от нёё избавится? Помогите пожалуйста!

Моё url:

```
path('categorys/<int:pk>/',CategoryDetail.as_view(),name='cat_detail_url'),
```

Мой view:

```
class CategoryDetail(DetailView,MultipleObjectMixin):
    model = Category 
    template_name = 'blog/cat.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context 
        

    def get_queryset(self):   
        cat = Category.objects.get(id__iexact=self.kwargs['pk'])
        if cat.posts.order_by('-pub_date').exists():
            posts = cat.posts.order_by('-pub_date')
        else:
            cat = Category.objects.get(id__iexact=self.kwargs['pk'])
            message_not_posts = 'Постов связанных с категорией "{}" нет!'.format(cat)
```

P.S И в моём queryset не может быть None,там есть статьи. Ну может быть и у некоторых категорий и нет статей, но даже на странице с категориями ,где есть статьи - выскакивает эта ошибка!

Comment: Ваш get_queryset просто ничего не возвращает, поэтому там очевидно None

Comment: если я начинаю,что то возращать,то мне выдает: 'Category' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: Потому что нужно возвращать не Category, а именно какой-нибудь queryset

Comment: Но мне в данном случае нужно выводить конкретную категорию что бы потом вывести посты связанные с этой категорий.

Comment: Значит возвращайте queryset, который выдаст ровно одну категорию, что-то вроде `return Category.objects.filter(id__iexact=self.kwargs['pk'])`

Comment: Потом обязательно попробую,даже не знаю почему и раншье не догадался. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: В общем я попробовал филтровать категории, как вы указали выше, но при этом мне выходит другая ошибка 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'posts' . posts это related_name поля ForeignKey(поле модели Post).

Comment: Как вариант я попробую использовать это в других методах класса DetailView